# How to give shimmer card's child in a list a unique "key" prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Tried to made a dummy id array inside another file and tried to imported here but still same error.
Here is my code

```
  return (
    <div className="restraunt-list" >
      {Array(15)
        .fill("")
        .map((e) => (
          <div className="shimmer-card"> </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Shimmer;
```

Error I am getting

```
index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the render method of `Shimmer`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.

    at div
    at Shimmer
    at Body 
    at AppLayout
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Can you show the error you are getting?

Comment: https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key

Comment: @Elikill58
yeah updated it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my question :

```
const Shimmer = () => {
  return (
    <div className="restraunt-list">
      {Array(20)
        .fill("")
        .map((e, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="shimmer-card">
            <img className="shimmer-image" />
            <p className="shimmer-card-heading"></p>
            <p className="shimmer-card-restaurant-name"></p>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).